# Sorting an Advanced DataGrid with Grouping Collection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I crate an avanced datagrd and grouping option to display data.
In my case, I'd like to display list of author with their books.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid height="350"
         displayItemsExpanded="true">
<mx:dataProvider>
  <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="groupingCollection"
              source="{bookList}">
    <mx:grouping>
      <mx:Grouping>
        <mx:GroupingField name="author"
                 />
      </mx:Grouping>
    </mx:grouping>
  </mx:GroupingCollection2>
</mx:dataProvider>
<mx:columns>
  <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="author"
                 width="150"/>
  <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="birthday"
                 width="100"/>
  <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="title"
                 width="250"/>
  <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="dateOfPublication"
                 width="150"
                 />
</mx:columns>
```

But even if my dataprovider is order by dateOfPublication at the beginning, after grouping, order is lost in each group.

Do you know how to force re order by dateOfPublication each group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the GroupingCollection2 seems to mangle the existing sort of the data source.

You need to define a sort function for each of the GroupFields - check out the documentation for GroupFields compareFunction.  For example:

```
<mx:GroupingField name="author" compareFunction="sortByDate"/>
```

The compare function takes two objects (elements of your data source), and returns -1/0/1 if the first item is less-than/equals/greater-than the second item:

```
private function sortByDate(item1:Object, item2:Object) : int
{
   // Whatever comparison function you want
}
```